# Call a c# function from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have C# code in which I have embedded javascript code.  The `CalculateSalary()` method is defined in the C# code. But when I try to call it from the javascript code, an error is returned.

Comment: Is this a web application? You can't call server-side code from javascript without the help of AJAX or similar..

Comment: You have syntax error so how can the alert work ?

Comment: In which environment are you working?

Comment: CalculateSalary() is not javascript. That's why it doesn't work. Is this on an aspx page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow man, this is so wrong.
Your c# code will run in another context (server, service, etc..) and javascript will run on browser context. You cannot call a method written  in your server directly from javascript. You need a comunication layer like ajax or write your CalculateSalary in javascript so it can run on client machine (browser).

Comment: Can you tell me How can I do it using AJAX?

Comment: Sure: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is the `<">` this should be replaced with `<'>` inside the script near javascript:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + name+"');CalculateSalary();</script>";
```